# Is Using JQuery's Urdu Editor Plugin compatible for grails framework.?

Tags: grails

I am writing a controller for sending URDU SMS. when i start searching on Google I found Using JQuery's Urdu Editor Plugin for front end. But its nor working.

Is Using JQuery's Urdu Editor Plugin is compatible with grails.?

Any other suggestion for me to complete my task.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , What is Urdu ?

**Urdu**

JQuery's Urdu Editor plugin provides the capability of converting any edit area on a web page into an Urdu edit area. It makes it possible to type Urdu inside the edit areas without the need of installing Urdu language support or the Urdu keyboard in the operating system. This work is derived from Urdu WebPad which is a javascript component that also provides the capability of typing Urdu in a text area on the web page without the need of installing Urdu language support or the Urdu keyboard in the operating system. Creating an Urdu Editor plugin for jQuery is a significant development since it makes it possible to use all the powerfull features of the jQuery framework alongwith the Urdu editing capabilities.[**[HERE]](http://tools.urduweb.org/jquery/docs/using_jquery_urdueditor_plugin.html#introduction)**

Then , as far as i know , there is not specificily designed plugin for urud in grails.you can take a [**look and search here**](http://grails.org/plugins%E2%80%8E)

But, your work is very simple.

1.you need to include the jquery library of udru in your page like if you use it in customer.gsp file .then you need to add it like this. on header part of the page.

**[if you need help see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956799/how-to-include-jquery-js-in-grails)**

Apparently  needs to be included in  (after ). The following actually works:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple GSP page</title>
    <g:javascript library='jquery' />
    <r:layoutResources/>
  </head>
  <body>
    Place your content here
  </body>
</html>
```

**or**

as ordinary as

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="UrduEditor.css" />  
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="jquery.UrduEditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

use this in your text fields like this...

```
<table width="63%"  border="1" align="center" class="table">  
  <tr>  
    <td class="table"><span class="urdu20"><g:textField name="firstName" value="${person.firstName}"/></span></td>  
  </tr>  

</table>
```

Then your job is done !!! I have not tested it though but ,try it and let me know ..